# Disable radio button with dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How can i disable radio button when click?

[image]

and the other radio buttons with the same position name.

this is the submit button to get the value in dropdown list

```
    <form name="fmNames" id="fmNames" method="post" action="vote.php" 
 onSubmit="return positionValidate(this)">
<tr>
   <td>Choose Position</td>
    <td><SELECT NAME="position" id="position" onclick="getPosition(this.value)">
      <OPTION VALUE="select">select
     <?php 
     //loop through all table rows
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($positions)){
     echo "<OPTION VALUE=$row[position_name]>$row[position_name]"; 
    //mysql_free_result($positions_retrieved);
     //mysql_close($link);
     }
     ?>
    </SELECT></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="See Candidates" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</form>
```

And this is for the radio button

```
  if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
  {
 echo "<td><input type='radio' name='vote' value='$row[candidate_name]' 
 onclick='getVote(this.value)' /></td>";
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to disable all radio buttons when one of these is clicked ?

Comment: yes in radio in the same position. CAn you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign all radio button with same name . May be `"radios"`. Now, in `javascript` get all radio-button using their name and loop through. You need to execute below code `OnSubmit`.

```
var radios=document.getElementsByName("radios");

for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  radios[i].disabled = true;
}
```